# How can we design mobile chatting XMPP server

Tags: tomcat

I have a [xmpp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) server design problem, I have been thinking and searching about this for a while, but cannot reach a decision, I hope experts here can give me a hint, really appreciate.

<Requirement>
   Build a mobile chatting server, this server should allow:
1. Register new user
2. upload user photos
3. edit their personal information.
4. User can chat with each other.
5. Release API and allow android or IOS to use.
6. Should be extensible, should allow us to add new features later without too much structure change.

<My question>
I know there is *OpenFire* open source xmpp server that we can use, but these two are standalone servers, they don't allow user to upload pictures, edit their own personal information, or some other activities.

So how can achieve this? Can we create all the add-on features on Tomcat server, and make Openfire working with it together?
Or can we create Plugin in openfire to achieve this? What is the best solution?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to upload photos over XMPP?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: [why not](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html)?

Answer (score 2):

The XMPP portions of the work can be handled by something like ejabberd. The rest of the work is up to you to implement, as a web-application of your choice (the choice is fairly unlimited, there are XMPP tools, sample components and related libraries in most if not all the popular web-app frameworks).